# Nodejs app crashes when trying to delete a not empty directory on cloudinary

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

When I try to delete a directory on Cloudinary using my API (written in nodejs), I get the error that the directory is not empty (normal) and the app crashes and I need to restart it.
Here is theerror:

```
{ message: 'Folder is not empty', http_code: 400 } undefined
{"error":{"request_options":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":"281316816918183:CDb7LmvgBfhnVABQsG9Oks4u0vM","host":"api.cloudinary.com","port":null,"hostname":"api.cloudinary.com","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/v1_1/dgreyehwz/folders/9ea364f98672f22279ec99f315c11087/images/aaaaaa","path":"/v1_1/dgreyehwz/folders/9ea364f98672f22279ec99f315c11087/images/aaaaaa","href":"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dgreyehwz/folders/9ea364f98672f22279ec99f315c11087/images/aaaaaa","method":"DELETE","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","User-Agent":"CloudinaryNodeJS/1.23.0","Content-Length":0}},"query_params":"","error":{"message":"Folder is not empty","http_code":400}},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: (no error message)\n  No stack trace","exception":true,"date":"Sun Nov 08 2020 17:42:02 GMT+0200 (Χειμερινή ώρα Ανατολικής Ευρώπης)","process":{"pid":2272,"uid":null,"gid":null,"cwd":"J:\\Projects\\NodeJS\\Development\\smartSignageDev","execPath":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","version":"v14.15.0","argv":["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","J:\\Projects\\NodeJS\\Development\\smartSignageDev\\index.js"],"memoryUsage":{"rss":76529664,"heapTotal":61935616,"heapUsed":36817504,"external":21319141,"arrayBuffers":19733004}},"os":{"loadavg":[0,0,0],"uptime":1854},"trace":[]}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The code I use to delete a directory on Cloudinary is:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

cloudinary.api.delete_folder(req.query.folder, function (error, result) {
        console.log(error, result);
```

The part

```
{ message: 'Folder is not empty', http_code: 400 } undefined
```

Is what the Cloudinary API returns for my delete request.

I am using the latest versions of nodejs and Cloudinary Node.js SDK.

Has anybody faced something similar or now what this error means?

Comment: Yes you right the **delete_folder** only would work if the folder that you are trying to delete is empty, will also look into this but feel is one has to first figure out how to delete assets within folder than within callback you then delete folder

Comment: My problem is that the app crashed when the error is returned. I managed to catch the error by handling it as an asynchronous exception, but I don't understand why it happens

Comment: Like I am said you are getting an error because most probably within the folder that you want to delete there are files and if that is the case you can not use that approach that because even cloudinary docs specify that,  ```delete_folder``` method is used when the folder is empty

Comment: The error ```{ message: 'Folder is not empty', http_code: 400 } undefined``` (undefined refers to the result) is because the folder is not empty. I posted this question because of the 2nd error which causes the app to crash